# Spring Framework does not find Authorities with right query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security

We have a problem with Spring.
Our Authentication Function does not find the record in the database to specify the user role.
You can find our authorities Query below, the user exists, but the authentication is done via an email(username) and the role table does only contain the users Account_ID.

Manually querying the database returns 1 dataset which is indeed correct, but spring is telling us the following:

```
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [Select Account_ID,password,activated from Account where email=?]
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://*****]
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT Account_ID,role FROM Account_Roles WHERE Account_ID=(SELECT Account_ID from Account WHERE email=?)]
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://****]
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG JdbcUserDetailsManager - User 'admin@admin.de' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'
DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider - User 'admin@admin.de' not found
```

Our Authority Query:

```
SELECT Account_ID,role FROM Account_Roles WHERE Account_ID=(SELECT Account_ID from Account WHERE email=?)
```

Our authentication Method:

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    String usersByEmailQuery = "Select Account_ID,password,activated from Account where email=?";
    String authoritiesByUsernameQuery = "Select Account.email,Account_Roles.role from Account_Roles join Account on Account_Roles.Account_ID=Account.Account_ID where Account.email=?";
    String authoritiesByUsernameQueryNew = "SELECT Account_ID,role FROM Account_Roles WHERE Account_ID=(SELECT Account_ID from Account WHERE email=?)";

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            usersByEmailQuery)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            authoritiesByUsernameQueryNew)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: execute the posted sql statement form any sql-editor: does it return the right values?

Comment: Yes it does, as i stated in the description above:
Account_ID: 1 | role: ROLE_ADMIN, we also tried joining both tables an using WHERE email=?, but it did not work either

Answer (score 1):

### PROBLEM SOLVED

The Problem was, that after the first query, the primary key was used in the second query, not the same parameter that was used in the first query, so the second query ended up searching for an email=1(Account_ID). To specify it:

```
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [Select Account_ID,password,activated from Account where email=?]
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/frozencat?useSSL=false]
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [admin@admin.de], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT Account_ID,role FROM Account_Roles WHERE Account_ID=?]
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/frozencat?useSSL=false]
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [1], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
INFO  AuthenticationEventListener - Login attempt with username: 1      Success: true
```

So the Queries now looks like this:

```
String usersByEmailQuery = "Select Account_ID,password,activated from Account where email=?";
String authoritiesByUsernameQuery = "SELECT Account_ID,role FROM Account_Roles WHERE Account_ID=?";
```